# How I can use numbers in vertico-indexed-mode?

Tags: vertico

Emacs 27

I enable `vertico-indexed-mode`

Here result:
[image]

How I can use this numbers (**0,1,2,3**) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commentary to the package says it allows to choose a candidate with prefix arguments.
For example you can do `C-5 RET` to select the fifth candidate (as if you'd hit `C-n` 5 times and do `RET`).

Answer (score 0):

`vertico-indexed-mode` seems to be an extention just to add sequential numbers, so I made a snippet that allows you to select it, for now bound to function keys (`define-key` other keys as you like).

```lisp
(defun my-vertico-select (index)
  (interactive)
  (vertico-next (if (string= vertico-preselect 'prompt) (+ index 1) index)) ;; If `vertico-preselect' is `first' or `prompt', it's mostly working but when `directory' the default value, is described as "Like first, but select the prompt if it is a directory", so the condition switch (the first list item is directory or not) is needed.
  (vertico-exit))

(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f1>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 1)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f2>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 2)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f3>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 3)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f4>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 4)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f5>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 5)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f6>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 6)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f7>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 7)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f8>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 8)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "<f9>") (lambda () (interactive) (my-vertico-select 9)))
```

Comment: OK. But why this numbers not works out of box? Why are these numbers needed?

Comment: I just found out about it, probably C-u <the number> C-n or C-p ? The comment in the source says "It allows you to select candidates with prefix arguments.  This is designed to be a faster alternative to selecting a candidate with `vertico-next` and `vertico-previous`"

Comment: Maybe just displaying it as a (sighting) scale, for the keystroke to repeat of Emacs standard feature?